# configure hibernate.cfg.xml for MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, xml, hibernate, ubuntu, jdbc

I tried to rebuild project settings from SQL Server to Apache 2 with MySQL.
I newly at JDBC and can't figure out all aspects.

I installed according this tutorial MySQL/JDBC Driver [Setting Up MySQL/JDBC Driver on Ubuntu](http://marksman.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/setting-up-mysqljdbc-driver-on-ubuntu/).
And test runs perfect after added this `.jar` file to project.

Content of `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- /MYPC:1433/Blog;instance=SQLEXPRESS local connection properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://streamer2005.softserveinc.com/_055_OMS;instance=tc;</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:mysql://nazar_art/_056_DB;instance=MYSQL;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">nazarsql</property>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->

        <!-- <property name="show_sql">true</property> <property name="format_sql">true</property> -->
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.Role" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.Region" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.CustomerType" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.User" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.OrderStatus" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.Order" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.Product" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.Dimension" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.OrderItem" />
        <mapping class="com.softserveinc.edu.oms.domain.entities.CreditCardType" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But this doesn't work correctly when I run from maven it failed.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: what are your error messages ? If you can post your pom.xml that will be helpful to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Sql server or MySql?.If its MySql then change the dialect type to MySQLDialect

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Comment: I need to change from Sql server to MySql. It should work only with this briefly correctness or we need to change more items? I completely newly with this topics.

Comment: change these and give it a try

`<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>`
`<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>`

make sure that you have relevent MySql jar